# Spring Batch command line parameters - series of codes?

Tags: command-line, spring-batch

Good day.  I could not find an answer for this from google or from the search 
in stackoverflow, so please be patient if I missed a post for it.

I need to run a Spring Batch (v3.x) using CommandLineJobRunner because we need to 
submit run parameters, including a flag to process all codes, or process a subset 
of codes.

I'm thinking we might use a parameter listing the codes (if the process_all flag
is set to 'N').  The params might look like this:

-Dexec.args="birthdayBatchConfig.xml birthdayBatchJob process_all=Y run_date=022017"  I plan to take the run day from the day of the run)

I would then add the subset of codes to process like:
code_list=[22 34 56 73 82 84 86 87}
...I would then get the code_list param and parse out the codes with 
a Tokenizer.
I'm doing some experimenting to see if this might work, but if someone has 
had to do this before, any advice would be helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking a simple way as this

1. Passing code list a single parameter as codes=22,34,56,73
2. In Reader or anyplace you need to use it, map it as

@Value("#{jobParameters['codes']}")
private String[] codes;

Spring will handle the split with commas separator for us behind the scene.

Let me know if you have more question

Comment: Thanks, Nghia.  I'll try it and let you know.